# Coma que separa los elementos de una enumeración

Tags: ortografía, rae, ambigüedad

La Ortografía RAE, pág. 320, indica

> "... siempre que estos [miembros] no sean complejos **y** ya contengan
> comas en su expresión".
> https://www.rae.es/dpd/coma

¿Es el hecho de ya contener comas lo que califica los miembros como complejos?

De ser así, ¿actúa "y" en esta frase como una conjunción explicativa?

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish Stack Exchange. No está claro a qué te refieres con "conjunción explicativa", ni tampoco la frase donde dices que se encuentra.

Answer (score 1):

> **¿Es el hecho de ya contener comas lo que califica los miembros como complejos?**

No exactamente.
El manual alude a la separación de elementos de una oración con comas "siempre que estos [los elementos] no sean complejos y ya contengan comas en su expresión"
La cuestión clave es la definición de lo que se denomina una oración compleja (o compuesta), que está explicada en [esta entrada de wikipedia](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oraci%C3%B3n_compuesta)

> Se denomina oración compuesta o compleja a una oración que tiene más de un sintagma verbal o, dicho de otro modo, tiene más de un verbo conjugado. A una cualidad sintáctica formada por dos o más oraciones simples que se han combinado entre sí mediante parataxis o hipotaxis (esto puede involucrar diversos nexos o elementos de relación, conjunciones, locuciones conjuntivas, adverbios, pronombres relativos, etc.).

**De ser así, ¿actúa "y" en esta frase como una conjunción explicativa?**

No realmente. La **y** aquí es una conjunción copulativa que actúa agregando la condición necesaria de que para poder usarse la coma, los miembros a unir no sean complejos ni contengan ya comas (para tal caso correspondería emplear el "punto y coma", (tal como se explica en esta [seccion 3.a](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oraci%C3%B3n_compuesta) del diccionario)

> 3. Usos
>
> a) Para separar los elementos de una enumeración cuando se trata de `expresiones complejas que incluyen comas`:
>
> *Cada grupo irá por un lado diferente: el primero, por la izquierda; el segundo, por la derecha; el tercero, de frente.*
>
> *Se dieron cita el presidente ejecutivo, Francisco Ruiz; el consejero delegado, Pedro García; el vocal, Antonio Sánchez; y el secretario general, Juan González.*

Comment: Sin embargo el DRAE no contiene ninguna definición de **y** como _aclaratoria/explicativa_: https://dle.rae.es/y.

Comment: Cierto, estoy revisando la respuesta.

Comment: @GJC he cambiado mi respuesta original. Creo que esta última puede ser de mejor ayuda porque refleja lo que pude investigar sobre lo que preguntaste